# Building an awards hall mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have a database that is full of statistics.

I know how to get the top 10 accounts with a certain statistic by doing something like...

```
SELECT money FROM accounts ORDER BY money DESC LIMIT 10
```

That would show the top 10 accounts for the money statistic. Say if I had 10 different statistics is there a way of doing query that will work out the position of the top ten players based on all the statistics? Or would it involve alot of queries and then to use my choice of language to display it?

Thanks

Comment: Kindly be more specific by `query that will work out the position of the top ten players based on all the statistics` -- do you mean that you want to evaluate the rank out of who is the top for each statistic combined? Like if account 1 is the top for 10/10 stats, he's on top, followed by whoever is the top for 9/10 stats, then 8/10, and so on...?

Comment: Yes I want to find the top ten overall based on all stats.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to come up with an order in which to sort them, you could add multiple sorts to the query, but it probably will not give the result you want

```
SELECT money FROM accounts ORDER BY money DESC, points DESC LIMIT 10
```

You could however come up with some scoring system, but that would imply a lot of queries. At least, per statistic it would be one, similar to the one you already wrote. Something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT money, account_id FROM accounts ORDER BY money DESC LIMIT 100');

$accounts = array();
$points = mysql_num_rows($accounts);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $accounts[$row['account_id']] += $points;
    $points--;
}
```

And repeat this for every score type. After that, order the array based on points  and you'll know the top list.

Comment: Yes I thought about this, just wondered if it was possible with one query

Answer (score 1):

You can ORDER BY one or more fields. You can also have calculated fields.

```
SELECT money FROM accounts ORDER BY money, balance, age, SUM(money + balance) DESC LIMIT 10
```